# python non-existing argument taken

Tags: python, class, arguments, typeerror

Yeah, so I've overcame problems with wrong execution order, thanks to you, but i have more of them.

xcv.py (former welcome.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
#-*- encoding: utf-8 -*
from definitions import *

def NewLabel(text, column, row, self):
    label=Label(self, text=text)
    label.grid(column=column,row=row)

def NewButton(text, action, column, row, self, sticky="N"):
    button=Button(self, text=text, command=action)
    button.grid(column=column,row=row,sticky=sticky)

def OnExit():
    quit()

class encode(Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        widgets().NewLabel(u'Welcome to Brunhilda GUI alpha v0.0',0,0,self)
        widgets().NewLabel(u'What do you want to do?',0,1,self)

 #       widgets().NewButton(u'1. Encrypt file',OnEncode(None),0,2,self)
 #       widgets().NewButton(u'2. Decrypt file',OnDecode,0,3,self)
 #       widgets().NewButton(u'Exit',actions().OnExit(),0,4,self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=encode(None)
    app.title('Brunhilda GUI v0.0 encoder')
    app.mainloop()
```

definitions.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import decoding
import encoding
import zxc

version="v0.0"

class widgets():
    def NewLabel(text, column, row, self):
        label=Label(self, text=text)
        label.grid(column=column,row=row)

    def NewEntry(self, text, column, row, action, key='<Return>', sticky="EW"):
        entry=Entry(self, textvariable=StringVar())
        entry.grid(column=column, row=row, sticky=sticky)
        entry.bind(key, action)
        StringVar().set(text)

    def NewButton(text, action, column, row, self, sticky="N"):
        button=Button(self, text=text, command=action)
        button.grid(column=column,row=row,sticky=sticky)
        print asdf
class actions():
    def OnEncode(self):
        try:
            zxc.encode(self)
            quit()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "goodbye"
            quit()

    def OnDecode():
        try:
            decoding.decode(version)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Goodbye"
            quit()

    def OnExit():
        quit()
```

When any widget or action is called out, it keeps on telling me it is being given too much arguments

```
TypeError: NewLabel() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Also, i have done terrible job with definition classes, i suppose, but i have no idea how to make them *better*

- **EDIT** 
  Okay, i get it now. I forgot i should add "self" to definitions in class.
  To be closed

Comment: You forgot to name `self` as a parameter of `NewLabel()`.

Comment: `NewLabel` does have a `self` parameter. It's just not the first one. (maybe you should rename that to `master` or something, since that's more descriptive)

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you are using `StringVar` wrong. You are creating a `StringVar` to associate with an entry, but then creating a second `StringVar` that is used by nothing. You need to create a single `StringVar`.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a parameter that represents an instance of a class, and will always be the first parameter to any function called by an instance of a class.

Say we have class A

```
class A:
    def b(self):
        print "hello"
```

To call function b, I first need to create an instance of A

```
>>> my_a = A()
>>> my_a.b()
hello
```

Now you might be wondering.. "Why would a.b() work if there is no `self` parameter given?"

This is because when you call a function with instance of a class, it automatically places that instance as the first parameter!

To make more sense you can think of it like this (which does actually work)..

```
>>> my_a = A()
>>> A.b(my_a)
hello
```